# Order by creation time in OpenEdge

Tags: database, openedge, progress-db

Is there an automatic way of knowing which rows are the latest to have been added to an OpenEdge table? I am working with a client and have access to their database, but they are not saving ids nor timestamps for the data.

I was wondering if, hopefully, OpenEdge is somehow doing this out of the box. (I doubt it is but it won't hurt to check)

**Edit: My Goal**

My goal from this is to be able to only import the new data, i.e. the delta, of a specific table. Without having which rows are new, I am forced to import everything because I have no clue what was aded.

Comment: I think sorting by ROWID() will help. I am not sure how far it is unique :(

Comment: No, sorting by ROWID will not help.  Rows can be inserted anywhere and ROWIDs can be reused.

Comment: Why do you think that you want to know what record is "latest"?  Understanding why may point towards a different and possibly better solution.

Comment: @TomBascom I want to be able to poll for new data. I am just looking to see if I can achieve it without asking the client to insert helpful metadata like timestamps. Obviously if I can't then I need to talk to them.

Comment: If you give more information about the table and it's contents, how often it's updated etc, perhaps somebody can help you. There might also be other data sources available for instance if the database has a web front you might very well have access logs that you can process?

Comment: Why do you want to poll for new data?  That "why" might also lend itself to helpful suggestions.  (One possible solution would be to consider using replication triggers.)

Comment: @TomBascom In my app I import all of their data from some tables, then out of that data we build new tables that work for our purposes. I need to poll for new data because it does not make sense to import all the data every time, which is sadly what I do given its impossible to know whats new and whats old. 

The data is four text based columns, nothing more. Not even ids.

Comment: I also updated the question with what I think is my goal out of all of this. Sorry for not being forthcoming with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Short answer is No - there's no "in the box" way for you to tell which records were added, or the order they were added.

The only way to tell the order of creation is by applying a sequence or by time-stamping the record. Since your application does neither, you're out of luck.

2) If you're looking for changes w/out applying schema changes, you can capture changes using session or db  triggers to capture updates to the db, and saving that activity log somewhere.

3) If you're just looking for a "delta" - you can take a periodic backup of the database, and then use queries to compare the current db with the backup db and get the differences that way.

4) Maintain a db on the customer site with the contents of the last table dump. The next time you want to get deltas from the customer, compare that table's contents with the current table, dump the differences, then update the db table to match the current db's table.

5) Personally. I'd talk to the customer and see if (a) they actually require this functionality, (b) find out what they think about adding some fields and a bit of code to the system to get an activity log. Adding a few fields and some code to update them shouldn't be *that* big of a deal.

Comment: Hey @Tim, see my last comment on the original question.

Comment: "use queries to compare the current db with the backup db and get the differences that way". What do you mean here? How is it possible to compare say an entire table with its backup without actually sequentially going over the whole thing? And doesn't that defeat the purpose of my little project? 

I have updated my question explaining the real purpose of why I want this functionality.

Comment: I changed #4 to #5 and added a new #4 to address what you're doing.

Comment: Number 4 would not work because I have read only access. But I can do that on my local machine, but even then, how would want compare two tables in openedge in a way that guarantees a fast lookup of the delta?

Comment: Create a new db somewhere on the customer machine or the customer site, and use that to hold your "last dump" table. All you need then is read access to the customer's db to scan the table, compare it to the "last dump" table in your little "side db", and then dump a "changes" file to send to your local site to update your records.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. One last question, how would one efficiently determine a delta between two tables in openedge? I am thinking the MINUS construct, but is there something more efficient?

Comment: Use two queries - one against each tables in the same sort order, then step through their result lists one record at a time. If a record is missing from one table or another, or there's a difference between the two - then you have your delta.

Comment: You will end up scanning all of the data. If the tables are large this will not be very efficient. You mentioned MINUS, that makes me think that you are hoping to use SQL. That will present unexpected challenges too. If you care about efficiency make sure that the customer runs UPDATE STATISTICS so that the optimizer has something to work with. It is very common for Progress applications to ignore the stated width of fields and over-stuff them. This tends to give fits to SQL programs.  The "dbtool" utility will scan the data and adjust SQL-WIDTH accordingly but it must be run periodically.

Comment: w/out an event capture mechanism, there's no way to avoid table scans on the two tables to get what he wants. If he's only doing this once every week or so, the lack of "efficiency" won't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer @TimKuehn.

Answer (score 1):

You could use database triggers to meet this need.  In order to do so you will need to be able to write and deploy trigger procedures.  And you need to keep in mind that the 4GL and SQL-92 engines do not recognize each other's triggers.  So if updates are possible via SQL, 4GL triggers will be blind to those updates.  And vice-versa.  (If you do not use SQL none of this matters.)

You would probably want to use WRITE triggers to catch both insertions and updates to data.  Do you care about deletes?

Simple-minded 4gl WRITE trigger:

```
TRIGGER PROCEDURE FOR WRITE OF Customer. /* OLD BUFFER oldCustomer. */  /* OLD BUFFER is optional and not needed in this use case ... */

  output to "customer.dat" append.

  export customer.

  output close.

  return.

end.
```

Comment: This is #2 on my list of options... :)